# Weird flex wrap positioning with vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with a number of cards inside. I want the cards to wrap horizontally within a scroll-able window, which is working for the most part, but there is a gap between the 2nd row of the wrapped items and the first, instead of lining up right underneath the first row.

[image]

When I remove the `overflow-y` and `height` that enable the scroll bar, the flex wrap works as expected.

Here's the rule for that container:

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1rem; 
  
  /* this adds the scroll but screws
     up the flex-wrap */
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n9w2vb0m/3/

Comment: Even though i am not entirely sure how it works (someone else might post a correct answer explaining how it works, therefor i post this as a comment) adding `align-content: flex-start;` to `.cards` will remove the whitespace in between the 2 wrapped rows

Comment: more info on align-content can be found here: [developer.mozilla:align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New CSS.
Now everything is as the author wanted, no distance between cards.

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
/*justify-content: space-between;*/
  height: 100%;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1rem; 
/*height:70vh*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bottom-bar{
 margin-top:auto
}
```

Comment: removing the flex-wrap will make the items resize rather than move to a new column, this does not fix or explain the issue OP is asking

Comment: Yeah, that's my mistake. I update code, everything should work

Comment: Well sort of yes, the white space in between is removed. but in your provided code it now shows `.main` having `justify-content: space-between` commented out, wich is not needed or related to op's question. and you have commented out the height, wich OP knew would fix the issue, but asked why does adding this height cause the issue. and you have not provided an answer to that. what if OP needed it to be `height: 70vh`? i love to see people trying to help others, but this looks like guess work, or work arounds. not a real answer to what is happening

Comment: This actually worked perfectly for me. I wasn't set on the `height: 70vh` (apologies for not being super clear), I was only setting the height so that I could get the `overflow-y` piece working. Giving the bottom-bar the auto margin was what I was missing

Comment: @ramon-de-vries I am trying to help a person so that he continues to work, and not dwell on this problem for a long time. The first time I misread the requirements, for which I apologize, and the second time thoroughly approached the issue.

Comment: @ramon-de-vries the author used 70vh to push the footer to the bottom of the page, I noticed this and changed it to another way without using height. maybe he did not know about my method and just used the height, which is also possible, but causes problems elsewhere